# Angular ngFor not working with mat-accordion

Tags: angular

Suppose the response of `categoryFilters?.filter` is :

[image]

**HTML Code :**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of categoryFilters?.filter; let i = index">
  <div
    class="FilterDirectory-titleBar"
  >
    <input
      type="text"
      id="searchInput"
      (input)="searchCategory()"
      class="FilterDirectory-searchInput"
    />
    <span class="close-search" (click)="item.showSearch = false"
      ><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i
    ></span>
  </div>
  <div class="card product-list-header" style="border: none">
    <span class="open-search" (click)="item.showSearch = true">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </span>
  <mat-accordion class="filter-product-expansion">
      <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="true">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header
          style="background-color: #fff"
        >
          <h5
            class="float-left"
          >
            {{ item.title }}
          </h5>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <span class="clearfix"></span>
        <ul id="searchUL">
          <div *ngFor="let items of item.value; let i = index">
            <li *ngIf="items.active">
              <a class="search-title">{{ items.title }}</a>
              <div
                class="card-body"
              >
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div
                      class="col-md-10 filter-col"
                      style="padding: 0"
                    >
                      <label class="radio-inline">
                        <p-checkbox
                          name="item.title"
                          value="{{ items?.uuid }}"
                          label="{{ items?.title }}"
                        >
                        </p-checkbox>
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-count">
                      <p>
                        ({{
                          items.productCount
                            ? items.productCount
                            : ""
                        }})
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
```

**Code in TS file :**

```
searchCategory() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById('searchUL');
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
      txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = '';
      } else {
        li[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }
```

In this below part of the code :

```
ul = document.getElementById('searchUL');
```

I am not getting the complete list of item names.

To be more precise, based on the 3 objects (in filter array) as shown in the above image, 3 separate filters are created with a search bar in each.

**But if I try to search the value in the "Categories" section, the search is not working because `searchUL` contains only the value of "Manufacturer".**

The values of only the first array (i.e Manufacturer) are coming in `searchUL`. The values are not looping correctly.

**Can anyone please help me resolve this issue ?**

Comment: I think your problem is here: `document.getElementById('searchInput')` you probably have 3 inputs with the same id. Your better approch could be to sent the `$event` parameter or `$event.target.value` to your `searchCategory` method.

Comment: @ShayD but by doing that, I will get only the searched key (using `$event.target.value`). I still need to get the list of items, to compare the matched term with the search key.

Comment: You can name your `input` with `#` like `<input #myInput />` and then use a condition to show/hide your expansion panel rows like `*ngIf="items.active && items.title.indexof(myInput.value) > -1"`

Comment: @ShayD as you mentioned in the first comment,  **you probably have 3 inputs with the same id.**, helped me resolve this issue. Thanks ;-)